# placing two table environments side by side (not one table separated by tabulars)

Tags: tables

I have 10 tables in 5 rows (two in each row) in a single column environment. I have used a syntax like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
        \caption{Set \#1}
        \label{ds1}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule
            \textbf{Name}&\textbf{count}\\ \midrule
            row1 & 750\\ 
            row2 & 350\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
        \caption{Set \#2}
        \label{ds2}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule
            \textbf{Name}&\textbf{count}\\ \midrule
            row1 & 499\\ 
            row2 & 699\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But now the publisher is asking me to not to use multiple tabulars in a table, rather use separate table environments.

I still want to have two columns of tables because the tables are really small. Is there a way to make columns of tables with different table environments (rather than multiple tabulars in a table)?

I tried putting each minipage in a different table environment but that puts the second table below the first one.

Comment: Two such simple tabulars show up next to each other in a row even without this `minipage` setup.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :  I do still need to somehow put those tabulars inside separate tables, i can remove minipages if that helps.

Comment: The problem is still the dreadful floating here. I am not sure that `table` environments are the correct usage here!

Comment: But that's what the publisher is asking for, If I understand you correctly. What would you use instead?

Comment: you can not have two table environments side by side in a one column document, but surely the publisher should only be concerned with the typeset result? what's the difference between tow \caption in a single table which you have, and what they are asking for?

Comment: you can use `\twocolumn` have some float pages of single-column tables, then go back to `\onecolumn`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I think the minipages are needed due to the captions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I'm not very familiar with the notations. This I'm quoting from their email: " Please place Tables 2–11 in their own table environments. They are currently in separate tabular environments in a single table environment."

Comment: your example does not work: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.9         \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule`

Comment: I can compile it in sharelatex without an error

Comment: edited the code, needed the booktabs package. sorry.

Comment: if the publisher/editor is asking for two separate `table` environments, s/he clearly doesn't know what s/he is talking about.  it's impossible in latex unless they're in a a two-column-per-page environment, and then the order would be "incorrect" unless there is only one table at the top of each column.  (in what journal is this to be published?  i'll be sure to stay away.)

Comment: @armen From the quoted email I gather that they want to separate each `tabular` into their own `table`-environment, and not have them side-by-side, but as separate floating environments, which the `table`-environment is.

Comment: it's plosone, and maybe they don't want to have multiple tables next to each other, idk. haha

Comment: @RunarTrollet , alright, thanks. That will look really bad, since the tables are really small, but if they want it...

Comment: unless you have too long linelengths, it shouldn't look too bad.

Comment: Well at least the printed version will take one extra page. The trees! haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to you could do this (note the order is down the column not across the rows

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\makeatletter
\setlength\@fpsep{55\p@ \@plus 2fil}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

\begin{table}
        \caption{Set \#1}
        \label{ds1}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule
            \textbf{Name}&\textbf{count}\\ \midrule
            row1 & 750\\ 
            row2 & 350\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}

        \caption{Set \#2}
        \label{ds2}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule
            \textbf{Name}&\textbf{count}\\ \midrule
            row1 & 499\\ 
            row2 & 699\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
        \caption{Set \#3}
        \label{ds3}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule
            \textbf{Name}&\textbf{count}\\ \midrule
            row1 & 750\\ 
            row2 & 350\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}

        \caption{Set \#4}
        \label{ds4}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule
            \textbf{Name}&\textbf{count}\\ \midrule
            row1 & 499\\ 
            row2 & 699\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
        \caption{Set \#5}
        \label{dss1}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule
            \textbf{Name}&\textbf{count}\\ \midrule
            row1 & 750\\ 
            row2 & 350\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}

        \caption{Set \#6}
        \label{dss2}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule
            \textbf{Name}&\textbf{count}\\ \midrule
            row1 & 499\\ 
            row2 & 699\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
        \caption{Set \#7}
        \label{dss3}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule
            \textbf{Name}&\textbf{count}\\ \midrule
            row1 & 750\\ 
            row2 & 350\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}

        \caption{Set \#8}
        \label{dss4}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}} \toprule
            \textbf{Name}&\textbf{count}\\ \midrule
            row1 & 499\\ 
            row2 & 699\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\onecolumn
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `\captionof{table}{captionText}` inside a `minipage`?

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\vspace{\intextsep}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    Foo & Baz& Bar \\
    \midrule
    A & B & C \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{Table of Foo}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    Foo & Baz& Bar \\
    \midrule
    A & B & C \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{Table of Baz}
\end{minipage}%
\vspace{\intextsep} 

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, but I'm not sure if it's acceptable, it's still using two tabulars (without a table of course). Again, I'm not very familiar with the typesetting of the papers.